# Babel's \selectlanguage{} resets \frenchspacing

Tags: babel, frenchspacing

I know that `\frenchspacing` is the way I ought to typeset documents today, but I happen to like the double spacing after periods. To enable them, I use `\nonfrenchspacing`. But if I use `babel` and issue a `\setlanguage{}` command, it resets frenchspacing again. Is there a way to set it once per document (and maybe language) so it doesn't get switched later on?

Comment: `\addto\extrasenglish{\nonfrenchspacing}` (and the same for each language) should do, but it's difficult to say when you don't provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)...

Comment: `\setlanguage` is not a `babel` command. Please, provide a MWE.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\let\frenchspacing\nonfrenchspacing}`

Comment: @tohecz: Thanks, the `\addto\extrasenglish{\nonfrenchspacing}` works fine.

Comment: @JavierBezos Look at the title. `\setlanguage{}`is obviously a typo! But we need an MWE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Latest releases provide some hooks which you can use for this purpose. If it applies only to a language or some of them, follow the procedure already explained:

```
\addto\extrasLANG{\nonfrenchspacing}
```

But if the setting applies to the whole document:

```
\AddBabelHook{nonfrench}{afterextras}{\nonfrenchspacing}
```

This line of code tells `babel` to execute `\nonfrenchspacing` after every `\extrasLANG` is executed.

Answer (score 6):

The way how to add some declaration into a language setting is this (preferably in the preamble):

```
\addto\extrasLANG{\nonfrenchspacing}
```

where `LANG` is whatever you need: `english`, `czech`, ...

---

The way how to enforce `\nonfrenchspacing` everywhere is:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\frenchspacing=\nonfrenchspacing
  \nonfrenchspacing
}
```