# Execute \addto\captions<language> for all languages in babel

Tags: captions, babel, abstract

I am creating a .cls-File that needs to use the abstract-Environment. In my design, the header of abstract is not wanted at all. So I did the following, which is working so far:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{}%
  \renewcommand{\absnamepos}{empty}%
}
```

It is not yet sure for which languages the class will be used, though. That's why I want to delete the abstractname for *every* language. Is there some way to achieve this without repeating the code above for every language contained in babel?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210254/babels-selectlanguage-resets-frenchspacing/210348#210348 , and the manual, sec. 1.25.

Comment: It looks wong to redefine only the name

Comment: @JavierBezos That looks like the most reasonable approach!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there any better approach you would suggest?

Comment: I would redefine the abstract environment so that it doesn't create a header.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Any hints on how to achieve that? What am I looking for here?